# In Firebase and Java, how to get value from datasnapshot correctly?

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, data-structures

Recently I use Firebase in my Android application and try to get used of NoSQL data structure but I met some problems.

First, my data structure is very simple:

```
{
  "user": {
     "userid1" :{
          "id: "userid1"
          "name": "Samantha",
          "age": 25
          "email" : "abc@gmail.com"
                }     
          }
}
```

So I wrote my Entity class like this

```
public class User implements Serializable {
    private String id;
    private String name;
    private int age;
    private String email;
}
```

When I want to get all user into list:

```
FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("user").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                    for(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot : snapshot.getChildren()){
                        User user = dataSnapshot.getValue(User.class);
                        listUser.add(user);
                    }
                }
            }
```

But if I want to change my data structure like this, I don't know how to do the same:

```
{
      user: {
         userid1 :{
              id: "userid1"
              name: "Samantha",
              age: 25
              email : "abc@gmail.com"
              posts:{
                 postid1: {
                     postid  : "postid1"
                     content : "content1" 
                          }
                 postid2: {
                     postid  : "postid2"
                     content : "content2" 
                          }
                      }
                    }     
              }
    }
```

I figure I have to create a Post entity class but how can I fetch list of user like before? Anyone can explain to me would be helpful.

Comment: Nesting data like you want to do is an anti-pattern in Firebase, and goes against the recommendations in the documentation on data structuring. See https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/structure-data#best_practices_for_data_structure

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nesting data like you want to do is an anti-pattern in Firebase, and goes against the recommendations in the documentation on data structuring. See https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/structure-data#best_practices_for_data_structure

---

That said: if you have a structure like this, you can read it by adding `posts` map to the class to read its data:

```
public class User implements Serializable {
    public String id;
    public String name;
    public int age;
    public String email;
    public Map<String, Object> posts;
}
```

If you want to get them type-safely, you might need to use a [`GenericTypeIndicator`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/database/GenericTypeIndicator).